# R file not writing the csv file in UTF-8 format

Tags: r, csv

I have set the following environment variables:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and I am writing my file with the following code in R:

`write.csv("acsv", file = "MyData.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`

However, when I run the command to check the file encoding:

`file -i MyData.csv`

I get the following as an output:

`MyData.csv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Comment: This is because UTF-8 is backwards-compatible with ASCII. Basically, UTF-8 _is_ ASCII unless special characters exist in the text. You should read up on what UTF-8 actually is and how it works.

Comment: @Nyerguds can you please help me out with some special characters that I can include so as to check whether I can differentiate between UTF-8 and ASCII? I actually read about both on Wikipedia and could not get any differentiating characters.

Comment: Literally any accented characters will do... as well as characters like the eszett, and special punctuation characters like the em-dash and ellipsis.

Comment: I am unable to type and paste any such character in the R shell. Please consider me as a newbie in R and help me out with example?
I appreciate your help all along..

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with R specifically. You can always use an editor like Notepad++ to create a text file in utf-8 that contains some of these characters; then you can read them out and do whatever you want with them.